# Pip import java error Cannot import java?

Tags: python, pyjnius

```
import.java.util.ArrayList;
import csv
import pynput
import.java.util.ArrayList;


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from array import array
from pynput.keyboard import Key ,Controller
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
Keyboard = Controller()






def csv_url_reader(url_obj):
   reader =  csv.DictReader(url_obj,delimiter = ',')

   for line in reader:
       url = line["URL"]
       title = line["Title"]
       print  (url+title)
       driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
       act = ActionChains(driver)
       driver.get(url)
       driver.find_element_by_name("q")

        #driver.find_element(by.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + 't');

       Keyboard.type("projectpython")
       driver.execute_script("window.open('');")  # opens new tab
        tabs2 = driver.windows_handles
       driver.switch_to().window(tabs2.get(1))



       act.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a')

       assert title in driver.title
```

i m trying to import Arraylist but i get a red mark on java

i tried to install java using pip install import-java and i get this error

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

I have tried everything but i cannot succeed please help me guys to resolve this

Comment: Are you using Jython?

Comment: i am pretty noob m using Cython i think.I get this error.Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aaiw86ha\pyjnius\

Comment: You can't mix java and python in regular python (AKA cpython).  You can in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).  But in this case you can probably delete the java imports and change `ArrayList < String > tabs2 = new ArrayList < String > (driver.getWindowHandles());` to `tabs2 = driver.window_handles`
`

Comment: Thanks but i get Unresolved attribute reference on 'switchTo'  on this line 
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));@snakecharmerb

Comment: Check the webdriver API docs [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames).  The default example code is Java, but you can click on the 'Python' button underneath the java code to see the Python equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the link.Still m not able to switch to different tab.Can u Plz tell why@snakecharmerb